# Как сделать одну большую картинку, а справа от неё два ряда маленьких

Tags: css, flexbox

Пытаюсь флексами расположить картинки таким образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но ничего не выходит

подскажите, как это осуществить?

Comment: А где ваш [mcve] раз пытаетесь?

Comment: @kizoso пытался, верстая макет. Изначально не понимал сам принцип, поэтому и примера никакого привести не мог, кроме как схематичного рисунка

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Отдохнул, зашел на кодпен и смог решить свою задачу самостоятельно буквально в пару строчек кода:
Всё [решение](https://codepen.io/arestch/pen/NwmeNx), в общем-то:

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(5, 5, 5, 0.6);
}

main {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  min-height: 1080px;
  box-shadow: 1px 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), -1px 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.container {
  padding-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="left">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/280x300" alt="">
    </section>
    <section class="right">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="">
    </section>
    <section class="right">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" alt="">
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 5):

На `display: grid` когда-то писал даже с фильтрацией https://github.com/kliford/Portfolio-Slider

```css
.new1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 256px;
}

.new1 div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.new1 .first-li {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="new1">
  <div class="first-li"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```