# Как расположить маленькие блоки справа от большого в два ряда

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Помогите пожалуйста расположить блоки как на макете используя flexbox по возможности.
 Пробовал разными способами никак не получается

```css
.exclusivephotos {
  max-width: 1170px;
  max-height: 570px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.img12 {
  height: 270px;
  width: 270px;
}

.img12:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 570px;
  width: 570px;
}

.img12:nth-of-type(2),
.img12:nth-of-type(3),
.img12:nth-of-type(4),
.img12:nth-of-type(5),
{
  height: 270px;
  width: 270px;
}
```

```html
<div class="exclusiveprod">


  <div class="exclusivephotos">
    <div class="img12"><img src="img/product-1-lg.png" alt="product">
    </div>
    <div class="img12"><img src="img/product-2-sm.png" alt="product"></div>
    <div class="img12"><img src="img/product-3-sm.png" alt="product"></div>
    <div class="img12"><img src="img/product-4-sm.png" alt="product"></div>
    <div class="img12"><img src="img/product-5-sm.png" alt="product"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572906/flexbox-layout-pattern-5-square-1-large-4-small

Answer (score 0):

Побробуйте так

```css
.exclusivephotos {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.big,
.small {
  width: 50%;
  height: 540px;
}

.small {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.big img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.small img {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="exclusiveprod">
    <div class="exclusivephotos">
      <div class="big">
        <img src="photo-1.png" alt="product">
      </div>

      <div class="small">
        <img src="photo-1.png" alt="product">
        <img src="photo-1.png" alt="product">
        <img src="photo-1.png" alt="product">
        <img src="photo-1.png" alt="product">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить с помощью этого ответа

```css
.main1 {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left:;
  min-height: 1080px;
}

.container1 {
  padding-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.right {
  display: flex;

  flex-direction: column;
}
.right img{
    padding: 0px 0px 30px 30px;
   

}
```

```html
<div class="main1">

            <div class="container1">
                <div class="big">

                    <img src="img/product-1-lg.png" alt="product">
                </div>
                <div class="right ">

                    <div class="img12"><img src="img/product-2-sm.png" alt="product"></div>
                    <div class="img12"><img src="img/product-3-sm.png" alt="product"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <div class="img12"><img src="img/product-4-sm.png" alt="product"></div>
                    <div class="img12"><img src="img/product-5-sm.png" alt="product"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[**

> `***текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом***`

**][1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/754397/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%91-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85?rq=1)